# Can't access updated value of scope variable in a scenario of multiple partial HTML with single angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a HTML associated with an angular controller which uses two partials. I smiplified it:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   <body>
      <!-- It calls one of these two partials for a navigation bar. -->
   </body>
</html>
```

**HTML 1:**

```
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-click="myfunction()">
      </div>
```

**HTML 2:**

```
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <br>
         Person Name: {{new_name}}
      </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "";
      $scope.new_name = "";

      $scope.getQuery = function() {
        $scope.new_name = $scope.name;  
      };
});
```

Now in HTML 2, `{{new_name}}` is empty string as declared in JS. But I want it to be as mentioned in input of HTML 1, I mean run time binding.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Angular can't communicate across different documents like what you have here. It's supposed to be a single page. Look into views.

Comment: @MathewBerg I updated my question. Is it making sense now ?

Comment: @Satpal I am using the same controller for this

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write ng-controller="myCtrl" a new instance of the controller is created. Which means a new scope is created. To see this, simply inspect element in your browser and put a break point at the beginning of your controller. You will see that two instances are created.

I would recommend you to have a different controller for every view you have. If you want to display multiple views into one page, you can look into [Ui-router named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Then, to share data accros those controllers, you could:

1. Make a service and inject it in both controller
2. Use $scope, having a parent $scope accessed by child controllers. (Easily done with [UI-Router nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)